# Is Rama Setu a historical proof of Ramayana?

Tags: india, religious-history, hinduism

Can Rama Setu be a historical proof of Ramayana?

Rama's Bridge or Rama Setu,[b] is a chain of limestone shoals, between Pamban Island, also known as Rameswaram Island, off the south-eastern coast of Tamil Nadu, India, and Mannar Island, off the north-western coast of Sri Lanka. Geological evidence suggests that this bridge is a former land connection between India and Sri Lanka.

**Age**

The studies under "Project Rameswaram" of the Geological Survey of India (GSI), which included dating of corals, indicate Rameswaram Island evolved beginning 125,000 years ago. Radiocarbon dating of samples in this study suggests the domain between Rameswaram and Talaimannar may have been exposed sometime between 7,000 and 18,000 years ago.[19] Thermoluminescence dating by GSI concludes that the dunes between Dhanushkodi and Adam's Bridge started forming about 500–600 years ago.[19]

Another study suggests that the appearance of the reefs and other evidence indicate their recency, and a coral sample gives a radiocarbon age of 4,020±160 years BP.

Please read this for more information : [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam's_Bridge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_Bridge)

Comment: Proof would be not right word to use, but it is evidence of Ramayana from reasonable standards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it cannot be. [This article](https://frontline.thehindu.com/cover-story/article30192969.ece) by Frontline magazine (behind paywall; you can download the full article from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iaGTpK2JxNBMUsFiyt9EDONknl3nEVz8/view)) says, the Archaeological Survey of India (ASI) found no evidence to indicate that Rama Setu or Adam's Bridge is a man-made structure.

> #### Shifting lines
>
> Print edition: October 05, 2007
>
> ...
>
> The petitioners, including [Subramanian] Swamy, referred to the
> ancient history of India, and the epic, Ramayana in support of their
> demand that Adams Bridge be considered an ancient monument. Therefore,
> it was important for the government to explain why it could not, on
> the face of it, accept the claims of the petitioners in this regard.
>
> The government found that there was no concrete evidence for the
> claims of the petitioners and that they just wanted a fishing enquiry
> into the history of Adams Bridge to determine their claims that it was
> historic and ancient.
>
> Therefore, the ASI analysed the ingredients of the definition of
> ancient monument under Section 2(a) of the Ancient Monument and
> Archaeological Sites and Remains Act, 1958. Under this law, to qualify
> as an ancient monument, the monument must be of historical,
> archaeological or artistic interest. In paragraph 32 of the affidavit,
> **the ASI concluded**: **In the light of the scientific study conducted, the
> said formation cannot, therefore, be said to be a man-made structure.
> The same is merely a sand and coral formation** which cannot be said to
> be of historical, archaeological or artistic interest or importance.
>
> The ASI was categorical that its obligation under Article 49 of the
> Constitution must be fulfilled on the basis of scientific study and
> analysis with total objectivity. Excavations of sites and analysis of
> physical remains form an essential part of this scientific inquiry,
> and **the ASI has so far not found any evidence to suggest that Adams
> Bridge is a man-made bridge.** It concluded that there was no merit
> whatsoever in the claim to warrant any action on its part under the
> Act.

According to [this article](http://archive.indianexpress.com/news/sethusamudram-in-dire-straits/31331/0) by The Indian Express, the natural formation is actually called a [Tombolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombolo):

> #### Not a bridge to the past, say studies
>
> ...
>
> The Government has conducted various geotechnical studies over the years to end the controversy. Before the project was commissioned, borehole investigations were conducted at 81 locations for up to 20 metres in the Adam's Bridge area. The then Union Minister for Coal and Mines Uma Bharati wanted the GSI to take up a R&D project to establish the paleography of the terrain. The GSI's Project Rameswaram between December 2002 and March 2003 dug up boreholes up to 205 metres.
>
> The study concluded that it is sedimentation. "Core sediment/logs of boreholes indicate presence of compact clay, calcerous sandstone and fossiliferrous limestone deposited in an episodic manner. The sedimentation pattern clearly points to the past sea level fluctuations about 5-7 lakhs years ago.
>
> **NASA**, shocked at the outrage, **clarified on its website, calling the formation a** "[tombolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombolo)", **which is a bar of sand connecting one island with another**. "[Such tombolos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombolo#List_of_tombolos) usually indicate a constant sediment source and a strong unidirectional or bi-directional (monsoonal) long shore current," they said.
>
> The government scientists seem to buy this. They say, "The Adam's Bridge area has a constant sediment source from the rivers flowing into Palk Bay and experiences bi-directional long shore current, due to the south-west and north-east monsoon." **This explains the formation of the Ramar setu.**

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer

Comment: @ dark bridge is man mdae recent studies have proved it:-https://www.patheos.com/blogs/drishtikone/2007/08/adams-bridge-ram-setu-man-made-structure-top-indian-geologist/

Comment: https://www.patheos.com/blogs/drishtikone/2007/08/adams-bridge-ram-setu-man-made-structure-top-indian-geologist/ ram setu is man-made why are you using old data?

Comment: Old data? The blog post you referenced is also from August 2007, same as the two news articles (May & Oct 2007). How come ASI is saying no proof of man-made construction while an Indian geologist is saying it's man-made? How do you decide who to trust? @SanatanDarshan

Comment: Here's the latest data from July 2020: https://www.indiatimes.com/trending/social-relevance/adams-bridge-myth-debunked-517505.html @SanatanDarshan

Comment: Also check this Tweet by a GIS/Remote Sensing expert: https://twitter.com/rajbhagatt/status/1280506327022829571 @SanatanDarshan

Comment: From March, 2018: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hu8s.png @SanatanDarshan

Comment: @sv. After ASI report, Geological survey of India made their report and C Badrinarayana was its head. So that's why I said old report

Comment: Look at the [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hu8s.png) from Minister for Science, Technology & Earth Sciences. This is from March 2018: "However the field geologic observation and drilling data **could not bring out any indications or evidences of manmade structures** in the present day seabed or in the sub surface level between Dhanushkodi tip and Adam's Bridge island within the EEZ of India." @SanatanDarshan